# App closing immediately after installing from google play-store - Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

Our app is closing immediately after installing from play-store although the same Apk is working perfectly fine when installed directly using Apk file.

The info logs is given below,

```
04-16 16:57:14.819 913-3772/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.xxx.xxx/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10019 from pid 1779 on display 0
04-16 16:57:14.848 1025-1025/? I/PackageChangedReceiver: packageName=com.xxx.xxx,mode=0
04-16 16:57:14.849 228-228/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:0,p:-1,c:228) setConsumerName: Starting com.xxx.xxx
04-16 16:57:14.849 228-228/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:0,p:-1,c:228) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1 height=1
04-16 16:57:14.871 228-228/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:0,p:-1,c:228) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1280 height=800
04-16 16:57:14.881 228-965/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:913,c:228) connect(P): api=2 producer=(913:system_server) producerControlledByApp=false
04-16 16:57:14.881 228-1989/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:913,c:228) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-16 16:57:14.899 913-923/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 15417:com.xxx.xxx/u0a512 for activity com.xxx.xxx/.MainActivity
04-16 16:57:15.381 913-1897/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.xxx.xxx (pid 15417) has died
04-16 16:57:15.652 228-247/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:-1,c:228) disconnect(P): api 2
04-16 16:57:15.653 228-247/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:-1,c:228) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
04-16 16:57:15.667 228-228/? I/BufferQueueConsumer: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
04-16 16:57:15.667 228-228/? I/BufferQueue: [Starting com.xxx.xxx](this:0x7f9dbc9400,id:285,api:2,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
```

So to debug we created one more application on play-store after changing package name, and it's working fine after installing.

only difference between the two play-store application account is that former one has app signing enabled while later which is working fine doesn't have app signing enabled.

So what is the exact problem, do we are not using app signing properly on play console OR is there any other setting that we have configured incorrectly or there is problem in our code?? Kindly help..

Comment: is your proguard configured properly?

Comment: this doesn't show why app was closed (crashed)

Comment: Yes pro-guard seems to be configured correctly, As if it doesn't then how does the Apk works directly also its working fine with account where app signing is disabled.

Comment: The app is not crashed, it app is not opening with application process died after showing permission dialog, even the UI doesn't shows up, only permission dialog shows and after allowing all permissions,  the app closes.

Comment: You're not sharing enough information. The logs you shared are only INFO logs. If the app crashes/closes on startup, you should have a stacktrace somewhere or at least some ERROR messages (marked with `E/SomeClassName:`). Also, when you're testing locally, do you build the release APK or the debug APK? Do you publish an Android App Bundle or an APK? If you publish an AAB, when you test locally, did you test also with APKs generated from the AAB or just the default APK?

Comment: App signing doesn't change your code, so it seems unlikely that this is the cause. You need to provide better error logs for people to help you debug - your logs don't show the crash.

Comment: When app is closing it also shows the following error line in logcat, Please see if it has some value E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

Comment: While in mobile devices, I shows few lines in logcat like following, 2019-04-19 19:38:00.431 7171-7171/? E/AndroidIME: bbm: Unknown property name: image_height
2019-04-19 19:38:00.432 7171-7171/? E/AndroidIME: bbm: Unknown property name: image_scale_mode
2019-04-19 19:38:00.432 7171-7171/? E/AndroidIME: bbm: Unknown property name: google_icon_background_color
2019-04-19 19:38:00.714 2304-2304/? E/PropertyValuesHolder: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2019-04-19 19:38:00.714 2304-2304/? E/PropertyValuesHolder: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: did you try running the app in release mode locally?

Comment: Yes, Release Apk is working fine when installed directly.

Comment: Also, I some device its also showing 2019-04-24 18:16:38.213 1997-3044/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.xxx.xxxom.xxx.xxxMainActivity/12 after that I/ActivityManager: Process com.xxx.xxx(pid 17922) has died: cch  CEM

Answer (score 0):

Work on progurad script to avoid this crashing issue. You have to add package over there. Thats what understood from your errorlog